# X-Appengine-Cron for basic scaling

Tags: google-app-engine

[This document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) says when invoking my app from cron, App Engine will add `X-Appengine-Cron` header. But when my app is using basic scaling, App Engine does not add this header.

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: go116

instance_class: 'B1'

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5
  idle_timeout: 1m
```

**myapp.go**

```
for k, v := range r.Header {
  fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, v)
}
```

**log**

```
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: [3cc37f2c74d426a6a32808ee1ee39157/8748841181108151557]
X-Google-Serverless-Node-Envoy-Config-Gae: []
X-Appengine-User-Ip: [0.1.0.3]
X-Appengine-Api-Ticket: [ChBhYWMyZjdhOTc1Njk2ZmIxEIS8rRcQj7ytFxoTCJ2dn9jN6PoCFWXzmwod5mkBmw==]
X-Appengine-Default-Version-Hostname: [myapp.an.r.appspot.com]
X-Appengine-Clientsideratelimiting: [true]
Traceparent: [00-3cc37f2c74d426a6a32808ee1ee39157-796a20b36c42a505-00]
X-Appengine-Timeout-Ms: [86399999]
X-Google-Internal-Skipadmincheck: [true]
X-Appengine-Request-Log-Id: [634dfea800ff08d49df8dcf2790001627e637562656c696e6b2d646576000162617369637363616c696e67000100]
X-Forwarded-Proto: [http]
Forwarded: [for="0.1.0.3";proto=http]
X-Appengine-Country: [ZZ]
X-Forwarded-For: [0.1.0.3, 169.254.1.1]
X-Appengine-Failfast: [true]
X-Appengine-Https: [off]
```

Does App Engine not add `X-Appengine-Cron` header for basic scaling? If this is true, how can I find the request is cron job.

Comment: Did you confirm it adds the header when your app uses automated scaling? You could also try checking the IP Address (the document you linked to includes a check via IP)

Comment: Yes, I confirmed automatic scaling adds this header. The document says cron request will come from `0.1.0.2`, but TaskQueue also comes from `0.1.0.2`. I can not distinguish these two requests by IP address.

Comment: okay. looks like a bug then. A workaround would be to add a parameter to the url endpoint (just for cron). This means anytime you see the parameter you know it was from cron

Comment: @N.F., did the previous comment address your concern? If so, please post it as an answer so that other community members with similar questions will find this helpful.

Comment: @RobertG I can not apply this approach because our users can fake their requests as if it is cron request.

Comment: In that case, you could combine both the parameter and IP address check. Your users could fake their request but they won't have the IP address. Your task queue might come from the IP but it won't have the parameter.